# Scroll to div but with margin difference

Tags: javascript, html, margin, pixel

With my javascript code i can scroll to a div, but i need the javascript to get me 20 pixels higher than that div. My code is this

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
              if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                  scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
              }
        }
    });
});
```

Can someone make it that it get `10px` higher than the `div`? Thank you very much

This is my webpage if you want to know the problem more specific about http://www.sventasticable.nl

My english isn't very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove 10 from `top`

```
$('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top - 10
    }, 1000);
```